# Neo4j: Create a big graph that size is about 6GB

Tags: neo4j

I need a big database for testing, but I cannot  find a suitable database.
The database has to have about 5 relationships. 
Is there the best way to create a big database?

Answer (score 1):

There are APOC procedures for [Generating Graphs](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_generating_graphs).

For example, this would create 1000 `Foo` nodes and 5 randomly placed `BAR` relationships, using the [Erdős–Rényi model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93R%C3%A9nyi_model):

```
CALL apoc.generate.er(1000, 5, 'Foo', 'BAR')
```